# Covering PCB antenna with lacquer

Tags: pcb, antenna, esp8266, pcb-antenna

In my project, I use ESP-12F module which has exposed (no soldermask) plated PCB antenna included in design. However I want my PCB to be waterproof and cover whole thing with waterproof lacquer.

My question is: will the lacquer influence the antenna's performance much?

Comment: Lacquer absorbs moisture.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The OEM designed the antenna with no soldermask probably for a reason. If you cover it with lacquer, the dielectric properties of the lacquer will be more like those of soldermask than those of air, which will have a significant effect on the antenna properties.

Comment: So is there kind of lacquer that would have little effect on antenna performance?

Comment: Yes, one that has the electrical properties of air.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if a layer of solder mask or lacquer is going to change the properties of the antenna, a drop of water on it will likely be even worse.

Comment: @ThePhoton I intend to close PCB in hermetic environment, however I want to protect it even further. It is funny that in ESP32-WROOM design antenna is actually covered by soldermask, and range is still quite good